# In a responsive layout how can I get divs to shrink uniformly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

http://www.designobvio.us/GoldGrid2/

heres a sample page.  middle of the screen there will be the content box.  When one resizes the browser window you can see the content box scale horizontally from the "right only!".

1. How can I get my content boxes to scale from left and right uniformly?
2. How can I make the boxes scale vertically when the browser window scales vertically?

If you use Google chrome a blank new tab has the effect i'm looking for where http://vvcap.net/db/4cqAV8lk02EkhsSerduF.htp

My codes super clean.
HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="inner-box">
        <!-- start of padder"-->
        <ul id='carousel_ul'>
            <li class="padder">
               <article class="web">
                <h2>01.03.12</h2>
                  <section>
                    <h1>Skollklubben.se</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque facilisis elementum tellus, eget ullamcorper magna tristique ac. <a href=""><span>details</span></a> </p>
                  </section>
              </article>
            </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Please browse the css from source. (its just too much to post)
Is there anything else I can offer to help get answers?  I'm willing to do the work/research I just don't know where to start.

Comment: it looks like it's just shrinking each box's width, not scaling them... Do you actually want to scale it all down, or do you want to shrink the dimensions like this, but have the background image stay centered? Also, however you're shrinking the width should work the same for the height as well. (just change "width" to "height", "x" to "y", etc)

Comment: hmmm could you be more explicit because i dont understand.  these boxes are scaling it is misleading b/c the backround-size is set to cover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using jQuery, this isn't scaling the content this is resizing it (like your example) except with the same aspect ratio:

```
// The margin between the objects and the viewport when resized.
var objectMargin = 50;
// The minimum size our objects will shrink to (percentage).
var minSize = 50;
// Define our objects and get their dimensions and position on the page.
var objects = $('article.web');
var objectOffset = objects.filter(':first').offset();
var objectSize = {
   height: objects.filter(':first').height(),
   width: objects.filter(':first').width()
};
objectSize.ratio = objectSize.width / objectSize.height;


// This is our function which resizes the content
var scale = function() {
   var windowHeight = $(window).height();
   var objectHeight = objects.filter(':first').height();
   // Calculate objects new height
   var newHeight = windowHeight - objectOffset.top - objectMargin;
   // Check whether object needs to shrink or grow.
   if (newHeight < objectHeight) {
      // Change objects dimensons if it isn't below minimum height
      var minHeight = (minSize / 100 ) * objectSize.height
      if (newHeight < minHeight) {
         objects.each(function(){
            $(this).height(minHeight);
            $(this).width(minHeight * objectSize.ratio);
         });
      } else {
         objects.each(function(){
            $(this).height(newHeight);
            $(this).width(newHeight * objectSize.ratio);
         });   
      }
   } else {
      // Change objects dimensions if it isn't above maximum height
      if (newHeight > objectSize.height) {
         objects.each(function(){
            $(this).height(objectSize.height);
            $(this).width(objectSize.width);
         });
      } else {
         objects.each(function(){
            $(this).height(newHeight);
            $(this).width(newHeight * objectSize.ratio);
         });
      }
   }
}

// Bind the scale function to the browser resize event
$(window).resize(function() {
   scale();
});

// Call the scale function to make sure the screen isn't small already.
scale();
```

This doesn't take into account what happens if the user resizes horizontally first, however it should provide you with a good idea of where to go from here.

Comment: You're giving me way too much credit.  I'm pretty lame with jQuery.  I've updated the webpage www.designobvio.us/GoldGrid2 , I'm getting a weird error.  It appears that the script only targets the first item; moreover, the script elongates the first object 100%width?  In the end this will all be converted to wordpress and each object will be dynamically placed from a get_content loop; so these need to be treated the same.  Lastly, you nailed the vertical resize, but is there a way you can move the resizing anchor point to the center so that the left side and top resize as the window resizes?